# Separating out .cu and .cpp(using c++11 library)

Tags: c++11, cuda, gpgpu, gpuimage, nvcc

I am trying to convert a c++ program I have which uses random library which is a C++11 feature. After having read through a couple of similar posts here, I tried by separating out the code into three files. At the outset I would like to say that I am not very conversant at C/C++ and mostly use R at work.

The main file looks as follows.

```
#ifndef _KERNEL_SUPPORT_
#define _KERNEL_SUPPORT_
#include <complex>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include "my_code_header.h"
using namespace std;
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
const int rand_mat_length = 24561;
double rand_mat[rand_mat_length];// = {0};
void create_std_norm(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rand_mat_length ; i++)
    ::rand_mat[i] = distribution(generator);
}
.
.
.
int main(void)
{
  ...
  ...
  call_global();
  return 0;
}
#endif
```

The header file looks as follows.

```
#ifndef mykernel_h
#define mykernel_h
void call_global();
void two_d_example(double *a, double *b, double *my_result, size_t length, size_t width);
#endif
```

And the .cu file looks like the following.

```
#ifndef _MY_KERNEL_
#define _MY_KERNEL_
#include <iostream>
#include "my_code_header.h"
#define TILE_WIDTH 8
using namespace std;
__global__ void two_d_example(double *a, double *b, double *my_result, size_t length, size_t width)
{
  unsigned int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  unsigned int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if ((row>length) || (col>width)) {
    return;
  }
  ... 
}
void call_global()
{
  const size_t imageLength = 528;
  const size_t imageWidth = 528;
  const dim3 threadsPerBlock(TILE_WIDTH,TILE_WIDTH);
  const dim3 numBlocks(((imageLength) / threadsPerBlock.x), ((imageWidth) / threadsPerBlock.y));
  double *d_a, *d_b, *mys ;

  ...
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, sizeof(double) * imageLength);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, sizeof(double) * imageWidth);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&mys, sizeof(double) * imageLength * imageWidth);

  two_d_example<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(d_a, d_b, mys, imageLength, imageWidth);
  ...  
  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaFree(d_b);


}

#endif
```

Please note that the `__global__` has been removed from .h since I was getting the following error owing to it being compiled by g++.

```
In file included from my_code_main.cpp:12:0:
my_code_header.h:5:1: error: ‘__global__’ does not name a type
```

When I compile the .cu file with nvcc it is all fine and generates a my_code_kernel.o. But since I am using C++11 in my .cpp I am trying to compile it with g++ and I am getting the following error.

```
/tmp/ccR2rXzf.o: In function `main':
my_code_main.cpp:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `call_global()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that this might not have to do anything with CUDA as such and may just be the wrong use of including the header at both places. Also what is the right way to compile and most importantly link the my_code_kernel.o and my_code_main.o(hopefully)? Sorry if this question is too trivial!

Comment: Could you add the actual compilation commands you are using to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not linking with my_code_kernel.o. You have used `-c` for your nvcc command (causes it to compile but not link, i.e. generate the .o file), I'm going to guess that you're not using `-c` with your g++ command, in which case you need to add my_code_kernel.o to the list of inputs as well as the .cpp file.

The separation you are trying to achieve is completely possible, it just looks like your not linking properly. If you still have problems, add the compilation commands to your question.

FYI: You don't need to declare `two_d_example()` in your header file, it is only used within your .cu file (from `call_global()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a linking problem.